# Распараллеливание вложенного цикла OpenMP

Tags: c++, openmp

Доброе время суток!

Пытаюсь распараллелить с помощью OpenMp вложенный цикл, однако моими стараниями время выполнения только растет. Если кто-то сталкивался с подобным, пожалуйста, подскажите как правильно распараллелить подобный вложенный цикл:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for (int j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
    {
        result += x[i] + y[i];
    }

    result  += x[i] * x[i]; 
}

return result ;
```

Спасибо за любую помощь!

Comment: n какого размера ?

Comment: Размер n меняется, максимально 20

Comment: Ну два сделать можете? Подберите m посредине между 0 и n и сделайте два цикла. А потом создайте массив m и разбейте на несколько частей.

Comment: Для таких маленьких подзадач распараллеливание не имеет смысла. Время необходимое на синхронизацию потоков превышает время выполнения задачи в одном. Попробуйте распараллелить задачу более высокого уровня.

Comment: Дело в том, что я пытаюсь распараллелить метод молекулярной динамики. Данный цикл считает потенциальную функцию (конечно, в реальном примере она намного сложнее), при этом цикл вызывается многократно (на каждом шаге, так же с помощью него считаются разностные частные производные). Необходимо просчитывать огромное количество итераций при разных начальных условиях, таким образом среднее время выполнения программы около 3 - 10 часов (в зависимости от шага). При этом параметры, например, n неоходимо менять, поэтому, как казалось бы, распараллеливание имеет смысл.

Comment: Всего 20 атомов в молекуле и несколько часов? Что-то нереально большое время расчета. Возможно, стоит посмотреть сторону более эффективного солвера кинетической подзадачи, который позволит увеличить среднею длинну шага по времени на 2-3 порядка. Но главное не пытайтесь распараллелить расчет для одного конкретного начального условия. Параллельте цикл верхнего уровня: в вашем случае - цикл по начальным условиям.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd335940.aspx В приведённом коде не показано вообще распараллеливание. Прочите статью, там всё подробно и понятно описано.

Comment: @Chorkov это корректно, поскольку я запускаю каждый раз МД для  различных отклонений от начального положения системы (т.е. координаты свдигаются на малую величину). Так чисто МД будет работать не больше 2х минут для каких-нибудь 300 000 итераций.